# Why can I bind this socket to ::1%2 when ::1 is on interface 1?

Tags: c, unix, tcp

I am trying to understand how the `sin6_scope_id` works for an IPv6 address in UNIX C socket programming. Specifically, I wrote this program that tries to bind to `::1%2` (so the loopback address on interface 2, if I got this right) even though my loopback address is actually on interface 1.

**I expect this to fail. But it binds successfully. Why?**

Here are the first 3 interfaces returned by `ifconfig -a`:

```
$ ifconfig -a

lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
```

You can compile this program with:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra main.c
```

Here's the commented source:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // Allow any IP address on the interface with scope ID of 2.
    const char *hostname = "::1%2";

    // Say we want to bind on port 80 (for http).
    const char *servname = "1337";

    // Store some information about the IP address wanted.
    struct addrinfo hints;

    // Save addresses in here.
    struct addrinfo *addr_list_item = NULL;

    // Tell `getaddrinfo` that we want an address for IPv6 TCP.
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    if (getaddrinfo(hostname, servname, &hints, &addr_list_item) != 0) {
        printf("Could not read addresses.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create a socket and bind it to the address we found before. This should fail
    // but for some reason I don't understand it doesn't.
    if (addr_list_item) {
        int sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (sock != -1) {
            if (bind(sock, addr_list_item->ai_addr, addr_list_item->ai_addrlen) != -1) {
                printf("Binded succesfully!\n");
            } else {
                perror(NULL);
            }
            close(sock);
        }
    }

    // Release memory.
    freeaddrinfo(addr_list_item);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's operating system specific - what OS are you running on ?

Comment: This was on Linux, if I recall correctly (sorry for the delay in my reply).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of unix the `%2` may be just ignored.

On some [IBM systems](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/inet_pton.htm), the documentation says:

> The above IPv6 text forms may include an appended zone indicator (if preceded by a % character) and/or an appended prefix length (if preceded by a / character). In these cases, the % or / **will be treated the same as a null terminator.**